# How to pull list of all the customer with first_name as alphanumeric value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table name clients, now I want to pull a list of all the customers having first_name as alphanumeric value as an example, jriqbal23, sam45del etc.

If I need to pull the details of single customer, I can run below SQL:

```
select customer_id,email,first_name,last_name,middle_name from clients
where
email='jriqbal23@gmail.com';
```

how to change this query for pulling the list of all the customer having first name in similar way ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What variety of SQL are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ???

Comment: Can customer have first name other than alpha numeric value?

Comment: I am using oracle, customer can have first name other than alphanumeric also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Oracle database, you can query client data with regexp_like:

Alphanumeric case:

```
select *
  from clients
 where regexp_like(first_name, '\w+');
```

Digits case:

```
select *
  from clients
 where regexp_like(first_name, '\d+');
```

Comment: thank you. got the desired result just one issue is there are certain records for a single email id which seems to be a test account. Is there any way to exclude those records which is having an email id like test@test.com ??

Comment: If these accounts are simple ones, you can use like. For example: email not like '%test%'.